# Paypal sandbox is not

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Till few days back, I was able to do the transaction using Testing sandboxes. However, since yesterday, it's not redirecting me to the paypal site once I hit the Paypal button/image. It' not at all moving. Though, I have not made any environmental or code change.
I am not sure whether Disuse/not using  the accounts for transaction for few weeks is the main cause of it? 
Is there any validity period for the Paypal Sandbox accounts?

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QJL8G4TL3GDR2">                                                                         
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/bnr/horizontal_solution_PPeCheck.gif" border="0" name="submit" id='PROCEED' alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" disabled="disabled" >
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/bnr/horizontal_solution_PPeCheck.gif" width="1" height="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="merchantfiesta@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="XXXXXXXXXX">
```

Comment: <form name="form1" id="form1" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QJL8G4TL3GDR2">                   
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/bnr/horizontal_solution_PPeCheck.gif" border="0" name="submit" id='PROCEED' alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" disabled="disabled" >
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/bnr/horizontal_solution_PPeCheck.gif" width="1" height="1">

Comment: Please show the code in your post (better than in comment ^^) and edit your title : it is incomplete. You'll improve your chances to have valuable answers

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Booking Charge">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://crs.fiestasystems.com/csp/crsdata/index.csp"/></form>

Comment: Since I am unable to put on entire code because of the lack of space.. below is the rest of the code that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Was the button created in the Sandbox? I'm not able to find the "hosted_button_id" value in the Sandbox environment but I can in the Live.

Hosted buttons are unique to the account that created them and can be deleted from an account. That means a button created in the Live site will not work in the Sandbox and if you delete the button the original code won't work at all.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Pat! I changed it and now it worked.
Extremely thankful to you and glad that somebody is there to see people post.
You have a great day!